# Redirecting randomly from index.html to another file

Tags: php, javascript, web

**Every time** a user comes to my home page i.e. the `index` file I would like a script to run so a different and **random** page of my website is viewed each time.

I would prefer to do this in either Javascript or PHP. The pseudo code of the index file I would imagine would look something like this:

```
var randomNumber = functionThatReturnsRandomNumber(10);
var urlRedirect; 

if (randomNumber == 0)
    urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder0/index.html

if (randomNumber == 1)
    urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder1/index.html

if (randomNumber == 2)
    urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder2/index.html

...

if (randomNumber == 9)
    urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder9/index.html
```

and then some code that redirects the browser to `urlRedirect.`

<del>Any thoughts?</del>

EDIT

I guess I need to be more explicit. Would someone please suggest how I could accomplish the above? Thanks.

Comment: Is _"Any thoughts ?"_ your actual question ?

Comment: Use an array for the urls, so you're not wasting the world's supply of `if()` statements... they're a finite resource, you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Javascript, use `var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);` to generate the random number between 1 and 10. And then use `window.location.href=urlRedirect;` to redirect the user to your chosen page.

Comment: This seems to me the most elegant answer. How come no up votes?

Answer (score 4):

+1 for excellent user experience.

As a user, you're better off doing so on the PHP level, otherwise there's inevidably a hiccup of `loading->page glimpse->loading->new page` (and as a visitor, i would feel sketchy if that happened).

But, as long as you have a list of "possible destinations" in mind, you can use something like the following in the top of your `index.php`:

```
<?php
  $possibilities = array(/*...*/);
  header('Location: ' + $possibilities[rand(0, count($possibilities) - 1)]);
```

though I'd probably couple that with either a session or cookie so it only works on the first visit (unless you want it to work every time).

Comment: You need `rand(0, count($possibilities) - 1)`; [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function expects a closed interval, not a half-open one.

Comment: @PleaseStand: Good call, thanks. That's largely due to debating using `rand(0,1000) % count()` over `rand(0,count())` to get better displacement. ;p

Answer (score 1):

Use a redirect header.

```
 <?php
 $location = "http://google.com";
 header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
 header ('Location: '.$location);
 ?>
```

For random redirection:

```
<?php
$urls = array('http://1.com',"http://2.com","http://3.com"); //specify array of possible URLs
$rand = rand(0,count($urls)-1); //get random number between 0 and array length
$location = $urls[$rand]; //get random item from array
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); //send header
header ('Location: '.$location);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP:

```
<?php
$randomNumber = rand(10);
$urlRedirect = '';

if ($randomNumber == 0)
    $urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder0/index.html';

if ($randomNumber == 1)
    $urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder1/index.html';

if ($randomNumber == 2)
    $urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder2/index.html';

...

if ($randomNumber == 9)
    $urlRedirect = 'xxxx.com/folder9/index.html';

header ('Location: '.$urlRedirect);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Redirection to a random sub directory:**

```
<?php 
$myLinks = array("dir-1/", 
    "dir-2/",
    "dir-3/",
    "dir-4/",
    "dir-5/");

$randomRedirection = $myLinks[array_rand($myLinks)]; 
header("Location: $randomRedirection"); 
?>
```

**Redirection to random web site:**

```
<?php 
$myLinks = array("http://www.my-site.ie", 
    "http://www.my-site.eu",
    "http://www.my-site.de", 
    "http://www.my-site.it", 
    "http://www.my-site.uk");

$randomRedirection = $myLinks[array_rand($myLinks)]; 
header("Location: $randomRedirection"); 
?>
```