# Redirect to random URL using php

Tags: php

I have tried using this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14281559/2461805)

```
<?php
    $urls = array('http://1.com',"http://2.com","http://3.com"); //specify array of possible URLs
    $rand = rand(0,count($urls)-1); //get random number between 0 and array length
    $location = $urls[$rand]; //get random item from array
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); //send header
    header ('Location: '.$location);
?>
```

But every time I open another tab and load `index.php` I still get `http://1.com` every time.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably browser caching.

When you send a 301 you are informing the browser that you have permanently moved a web address to the one you are providing, so the browser naturally assumes that you truly mean **permanently** and he will only use that address in the future without asking the server.

Use a `307: Temporary Redirect` header if you want temporary redirection.